# Detect the Type of Active TextField

Tags: ios, swift, ios-keyboard-extension

I am working on keyboard extension I need to detect the input type of currently active textField. For example if Address textField is active in Message app I need to show "@" button in main screen of keyboard.

as in keyboard extension we can't access UITextField directly so is use UITextDocumentProxy I use the following two ways

```
    1-    let contentType = textDocumentProxy.textContentType

    2-    override func textWillChange(_ textInput: UITextInput?) {

            print(textInput?.keyboardType)
    }
```

in both cases I got nil. 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

There are third party custom keyboards available that you can use in your app. You can manage behavior of custom keyboards also.

[image: Keyboard]

Comment: you can't access UITextField directly while creating an keyboard extension. The  only way to access textfield is UITextDocumentProxy. so, it will be useful if using textfield from storyboard not from keyboard extension